# How to create link pages (read more links)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, list

On my home page I am displaying some news. Every news has "read more" button clicking on which will take user to news detail page. I was thinking about doing in SharePoint like following. Please let me know if my approach is right or you do things differently.

1- Create a list at back end that will hold news

2- Create a web part on home page where let's say top 5 news will be displayed form that list with "read more" links. The link will be something like:

```
http://myserver.com/mysite/English/Pages/News.aspx?id=5
```

3- For news detail, create another page to which we will pass the ID of news through GET (as shown in previous step)

4- Create web part for that news detail page which will take that ID, and then read list to display news detail

Is this how it is done in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

If all your news is in one site collection, just use the Content Query Web part which will fetch your news articles. You can filter them there and use custom xsl for rendering etc.

If your news is scattered all over the place (multiple web apps), use Core Results web part (ie Search). Create a custom search scope, managed properties if needed, and configure the web part how you like.

The web parts display a roll-up of your news. The links contained will navigate to the actual pages.

Comment: Ok I added "Content Query" web part but it is not showing any "read more" or related link. Instead it is displaying complete list (which contain 3 items) on home page. Secondly I don't see any customization options to apply my own CSS.

Comment: You need to customise the default xslt and use that with the web part. That's the SharePoint way of doing things. The html that is being rendered can be customised and you can throw in your own classes or however you want it to be rendered.